# Winform app for Mac

Tags: winforms

How to develop winforms (like .net winforms) for Mac Os?

What language needs to be used if need to develop app quickly, if there is lot of overhead using .net for Mac?

Please share your quick useful thoughts.

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Answer (score 2):

Mono, if you are used to develop in C# .Net.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)
http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page